# ArrayList not storing value

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a mailing system, and theres is a small bug that I can't figure out. I am posting all the classes in case whoever is reading needs it to understand anything, however I obviously don't expect people to read through all of it.

The problem that comes up is that when I run the main, I am able to create a username, however after creating it, the username is not stored.

I think the error either lies in main or UserList class, but I just can't find it. I put comments where i think the error is.

Sorry if my post is too long and/or not correctly formatted. I will take out any unneeded code, just tell me what needs to go!

```
/**
 * Created by Broomhead0 on 4/11/14.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Userlist
{

    //private User[] users; // this is an array that will store references to all users
    ArrayList<User> users;  //this is an arraylist that will store references to all users


    private int numberUsr; // this is the number of users that is currently stored in the user. Always smaller or equal to maxUser

    public Userlist()
    {

        users = new ArrayList<User>();
        numberUsr = 0;  // at start no user stored yet
    }

    // find a user in the list based on the username
    public User findUser(String username)
    {
        // iterate through the array; only iterate according to how many users are currently in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < numberUsr; i++)
        {
            // access the particular user through users.(i), then get the name,
            // and call the equals method on that name to compare it with the input username
            if (users.get(i).userName.equals(username)){
                return users.get(i);
            }

        }
        // no user found
        return null;
    }
//ERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERROR
    // add a user to the list; only do so if the user does not yet exist
    public void addUser(User u)
    {
        if (findUser(u.userName) != null) //if there is a match,
            System.out.println("User already exists");
        else //if there is not match
        {
           users.add(u); //add the username
        }
//ERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERRORERROR

    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted *masses* of code here. Please try to reduce this to a much, much smaller program which still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Create a minimal, complete, verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try to write a small (like 10 lines) program that demonstrates the problem.  That will help YOU narrow down what the problem really is, and help US be able to figure it out easily.  No one is going to read through pages of code to help you with one small detail.

Comment: Search for new user from the Arraylist after you add to it and check if it exists. It will help you in debugging

Comment: Your `numberUsr` field is redundant. `ArrayList` maintains it's elements' count itself (`size():int` method in Collection interface).

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be too large. Sorry, I'm still new here.

@Krzysztof Jabłoński, thanks! that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numberUsr stays 0 after you add a new user. Increase that when you add a new user or better use `users.size()` when looping over the users.

```
public User findUser(String username)
{
    // iterate through the array; only iterate according to how many users are currently in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
    {
        // access the particular user through users.(i), then get the name,
        // and call the equals method on that name to compare it with the input username
        if (users.get(i).userName.equals(username)){
            return users.get(i);
        }

    }
    // no user found
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @quaertym and Krzysztof for a quick answer!